# undefined method error for :commenter in RailsGuides tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working through the RailsGuides blog tutorial and am stuck:

The error message I'm seeing reads:
undefined method `commenter' for #

The code looks like this:

```
<h1><%= @article.title %></h1>
<br>
<p><%= @article.text %></p>

<h2>Comments</h2>
<% @article.comments.each do |c| %>
  <p>Commenter: <%= c.commenter %></p>
  <p>Comment: <%= c.body %></p>
<% end %>

<h2>Add a comment:</h2>
<%= form_for([@article, @article.comments.build]) do |f| %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :commenter %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :commenter %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :body %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>

<% end %>
```

The weird thing to me is that if I delete the ":commenter" section, the form works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think I didn't enter the name right when I created the model - got it to work the second time around.